How can I compare fields between two JSON objects and create a third JSON object with the results?
If a property from the first JSON object is not present in the second JSON object, the third JSON object should include that property with an empty value.
Request:
{
  "request1": {
    "firm": {
      "item": [
        {
          "Du": "1234",
          "Gu": "123",
          "DuNm": "QWERTy",
          "Don":{
            "donType":"Modern",
            "donValue":"0002"
          }
          
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "request2": {
    "firm": {
      "item": [
        {
          "Du": "999999999",
          "Gu": "999999999",
          "GuNm": "Sample",
          "Mad":"Fluffy",
          "isInt":true,
          "Dusky":{
            "duskyType":"Modern",
            "duskyValue":"0002"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Desired Response:
{
  "original": {
    "Du": "999999999",
    "Gu": "999999999",
    "DuNm": "",
      "Don":{}
  }
}

Jolt:
Jolt I am trying so far
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "request1": {
        "firm": {
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "@5,request2.firm.item": {
                  "*": {
                    "@(&1)": "original.&2"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Output I am getting:
{
  "original" : {
    "Du" : "999999999",
    "Gu" : "999999999"
  }
}

I want to check if the field in request1 is there or not in request2, if it is then add it in the response with the value present in request2. if the String field is not there in request2 then the its value should go as "" in output.if the Object field is not there in request2 then the its value should go as {} in output. The request1 and request2 can have multiple different fields at each time.

Can you show us what spec have you tried so far?

@BarbarosÖzhan could you please take a look, I have updated my jolt spec
